# C - ceil/float rounding to int guarantees

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

I'm wondering if there are any circumstances where code like this will be incorrect due to floating point inaccuracies:

```c
#include <math.h>

// other code ...

float f = /* random but not NAN or INF */;

int i = (int)floorf(f);

// OR

int i = (int)ceilf(f);
```

Are there any guarantees about these values? If I have a well-formed `f` (not NAN or INF) will `i` always be the integer that it rounds to, whichever way that is.

I can image a situation where (with a bad spec/implementation) the value you get is the value just below the true value rather than just above/equal but is actually closer. Then when you truncate it actually rounds down to the next lower value.

It doesn't seem possible to me given that integers can be exact values in ieee754 floating point but I don't know if `float` is guaranteed to be that standard

Comment: `float` is not guaranteed to be IEEE754, but on most systems, it is. So this question is *very* theoretical.

Comment: You mean what will happen if `f` is rounding to an integer, that cannot be represented as `float`? That can happen, and it is interesting.

Comment: I mean, float values can be way out of range for an int, like 1E38.    Try getting 10000000000000000000000000000000000000  into an `int`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey The behavior of converting a real value to integer whose integral part cannot be represented in the target type is undefined. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p1

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `f` is defined to be a `float`. It cannot round to an integer that cannot be represented as a `float`. If you mean `floorf(f)`, then the C standard’s specification of the floating-point formats guarantees that the `floor` of any finite `float` is representable in `float`; it can be represented merely by setting digits in the floating-point representation of `f` to zero. `ceilf(f)` is also always representable, for more complicated reason, unless it overflows to ∞.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The floor/ceiling statements above are for positive `f`. For negative values, swap them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard is sloppy in specifying floating-point behavior, so it is technically not completely specified that `floorf(f)` produces the correct floor of `f` or that `ceilf(f)` produces the correct ceiling of `f`.

Nonetheless, no C implementations I am aware of get this wrong.

If, instead of `floorf(some variable)`, you have `floorf(some expression)`, there are C implementations that may evaluate the expression in diverse ways that will not get the same result as if IEEE-754 arithmetic were used throughout.

If the C implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`, it should evaluate the expressions using IEEE-754 arithmetic.

Nonetheless, `int i = (int)floorf(f);` is of course not guaranteed to set `i` to the floor of `f` if the floor of `f` is out of range of `int`.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. I just didn't want it to take something like 3.999f then floor it to 2.999999999999f then truncate that to 2 sort of thing. So as long as I don't use some obscure architecture or compiler this shouldn't happen?